# Quantum Katas - Tutorials - SingleQubitGates - Exercise 2 - GlobalPhaseI

Tags: programming, q#

Program.qs

```
namespace Quantum.Kata.SingleQubitGates {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    
    
     operation GlobalPhaseI (q : Qubit) : Unit is Adj+Ctl {
        X(q);
        Z(q);
        Y(q);

    }
}
```

Reference.qs

```
namespace Quantum.Kata.SingleQubitGates {
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    

    
    operation GlobalPhaseI_Reference (q : Qubit) : Unit is Adj+Ctl {
        X(q);
        Z(q);
        Y(q);
    }
}
```

Test.qs

```
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;
    

    operation ControlledArrayWrapperOperation (op : (Qubit => Unit is Adj+Ctl), qs : Qubit[]) : Unit is Adj+Ctl {
        Controlled op([qs[0]], qs[1]);
    }

    operation AssertEqualOnZeroState (testImpl : (Qubit => Unit is Ctl), refImpl : (Qubit => Unit is Adj+Ctl)) : Unit {
        using (qs = Qubit[2]) {
            within {
                H(qs[0]);
            }
            apply {
               
                Controlled testImpl([qs[0]], qs[1]);

              
                Adjoint Controlled refImpl([qs[0]], qs[1]);
            }

          
            AssertAllZero(qs);
        }
    }

    operation T2_GlobalPhaseI_Test () : Unit {
        AssertOperationsEqualReferenced(2, ControlledArrayWrapperOperation(GlobalPhaseI, _), ControlledArrayWrapperOperation(GlobalPhaseI_Reference, _));
    }
```

Driver.cs

```
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.XUnit;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;

using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace Quantum.Kata.SingleQubitGates
{
    public class TestSuiteRunner
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;

        public TestSuiteRunner(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            this.output = output;
        }

        /// <summary>
   
        /// </summary>
        [OperationDriver(TestNamespace = "Quantum.Kata.SingleQubitGates")]
        public void TestTarget(TestOperation op)
        {
            using (var sim = new QuantumSimulator())
            {
    
                sim.OnLog += (msg) => { output.WriteLine(msg); };
                sim.OnLog += (msg) => { Debug.WriteLine(msg); };
                op.TestOperationRunner(sim);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this sequence of gates will work to apply the global phase of $i$. You can check it using matrix multiplication - a product of matrices $Y \cdot Z \cdot X$ will give you a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix}$, which corresponds to applying a global phase.

Alternatively, you can implement it using [R gate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r) with the phase $-\pi$: `R(PauliI, -PI(), q);`

As a side note, performing measurements this way is not going to detect a global phase introduced by the gate; you need to work with a controlled version of the gate to detect it.

Comment: I tried to work with a controlled version of the gate but I could not add a Entry Potint and run it. 

How can I run the code with a controlled version ?

Comment: EntryPoint and controlled version of the gate are completely unrelated. What exactly didn't work for you? You just need to allocate two qubits, prepare the first one in the |+⟩ state and apply controlled gate with the first qubit as control and second as target.

Comment: I updated my question with your answer. I used this codes from Katas but I did not get an output when I run it. Is it because they are Unit type?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've pasted writes anything to the output. You can use Message to output classical values and DumpMachine to output internal state of the quantum simulator.

Answer (score 1):

On IBM Q, you can also use $U3$ gate to prepare a global phase operator.
$U3$ gate is defined as
$$
U3(\theta, \varphi, \lambda) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (\theta/2) & -\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda}\sin(\theta/2) \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\varphi}\sin(\theta/2) & \mathrm{e}^{i(\varphi + \lambda)}\cos(\theta/2)\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Setting $\theta = \pi$ we get
$$
U3(\pi, \varphi, \lambda) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\mathrm{e}^{i\lambda} \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\varphi} & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let's denote our global phase $\alpha$ and set $\varphi = \alpha$ and $\lambda = \alpha + \pi$. Since $-\mathrm{e}^{i\pi}=1$ we have
$$
U3(\pi, \alpha, \alpha+\pi) =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\alpha} \\
\mathrm{e}^{i\alpha} & 0\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is $\mathrm{e^{i\alpha}}X$. To get $\mathrm{e^{i\alpha}}I$, we apply another $X$ gate.

**So, global phase gate is implemented as $X\,\,U3(\pi,\alpha,\alpha+\pi)$, where $\alpha$ is global phase.**

---

**EDIT (solution in Q#)**

A $R1$ gate is defined as
$$
R1(\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

An operation $X\,R1(\theta)$ is described by matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If we apply this operation twice (i.e. $[X\,R1(\theta)]^2$ ), we get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} & 0  \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i\theta}
\end{pmatrix},
$$

which is a global phase gate with arbitrary phase $\theta$.

**So, global phase gate in Q# can be realized as $[X\,R1(\theta)]^2$.**

Comment: I am focusing on Q# language, thanx a lot for your answer.

Comment: @theRomanMercury: Sorry, I did not take this into account. Please find solution (global phase gate with arbitrary phase) with $R1$ and $X$ gates for Q#.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, but I can not comment on @Martin Vesely answer [above](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12618/12280).
I am glad that my amendments have already been adopted, I’ll leave only a short note, in case someone is interested in this:
In Qiskit programs (e.g. [see](https://gist.github.com/Zhuravlev-A-E/a9fdeb5bb555b177e9e26b6c9fa411e7)) I use X before U3 in my variants of phase shift circuits,
in an attempt to avoid "distortion" during further processing of Qiskit (for example, by transpiler):

```
qc.x(qubit)
qc.u3(np.pi, gamma, np.pi + gamma, qubit)
```

If not for similar considerations, then the order here would not be important (as in other similar cases, e.g. $[X\,R1(\theta)]^2 = [R1(\theta)\,X]^2$)